# NullPointerException in Intelli J javafx CRUD

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, nullpointerexception, crud

I am trying to build javafx CRUD model with intellij and when I run the Main.java, Login window pops up. And when I type the correct username and password, another popup window in table so that where data can be created, read, updated and deleted.

After I typed correct password and username, Login window appeared, however, I faced NullPointerException in console as below.
When I hit Login button. I went back to two lines stated;

> 1. sortFilterTableView();
> 2. searchTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

there were no issues found. In other java and fxml files are all error-free. I rebuilt the project and ran it again many times but they didn't work showing me this same error. Any advice where should I begin to examine? Thank you. (Localhost is connected)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSKkx.png)

Error in a console box

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --add-modules
> javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/232/lib/idea_rt.jar=40981:/snap/intellij-idea-community/232/bin
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/home/marie/IdeaProjects/CosmeticsJavaFX/src/out/production/CosmeticsJavaFX:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar:/home/marie/Downloads/mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar
> -m CosmeticsJavaFX/application.Main
>
> wwww
>
> wwww
>
> Password matches
>
> Radio button selected: null
>
> User ID is: 9
>
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
> java.lang.NullPointerException    **at
> CosmeticsJavaFX/application.DatabaseController.sortFilterTableView(DatabaseController.java:186)
> at
> CosmeticsJavaFX/application.DatabaseController.lambda$initialize$4(DatabaseController.java:101)**
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

**DatabaseController.java:101**

```
        @FXML
private void initialize(){
    //initialize the tableView with four columns
    itemIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().itemIdProperty());
    userIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().userIdProperty());
    labelColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().labelProperty());
    brandColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().brandProperty());

    setVisibleItems();

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //fill the tableView with data from observableList
        try {
        System.out.println("User ID is: " + userId);
        tableView.setItems(getCosmeticsData());

        buildCosmetics();
        //line 101 below
        sortFilterTableView();
        //

        observeRadioButtonChanges();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
}
```

**DatabaseController.java:186**

```
    private void sortFilterTableView() throws SQLException {

    FilteredList<Cosmetics> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(getCosmeticsData(), p -> true);
    //this is line 186 below
    searchTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    //

        filteredList.setPredicate(cosmetics -> {
            //if search text is empty display all cosmetics
            if(newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (cosmetics.getLabel().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true; // search string is a match
            } else if(cosmetics.getBrand().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true; // search string is a match
            }
            return false; //does not match
        });
    });
SortedList<Cosmetics> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
tableView.setItems(sortedList);

}
```

**Main.java**

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AddressScene.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

        // open the login scene

         stage.setTitle("Server Address");
         stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
         stage.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: The only way you can get that exception is if `searchTextField` is null.

Comment: Why the `Platform.runLater()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java variable searchTextField has a corresponding FXML element with a matching fx:id

<TextField fx:id="searchTextField" .........

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue! Thank you :)